# Run a function synchronously in another thread

Tags: java, android

How can I run a function synchronously in another thread, meaning the main UI thread has a function that calls another function that does its work on another thread, waits for the new thread to finish and returns the value:

```
int mainFunction() //this function is on the main UI thread
{
   return doWorkOnNewThread();
}

int doWorkOnNewThread()
{
   //do work on new thread
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of blocking the main UI thread? If the operation takes too long, you'll get an ANR.

Comment: I need the value from the second thread before I can continue the work on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Async task for this, even though it's asynchronous. You can use the callbacks onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate to update the values as needed. I should also note you probably don't want to do this synchronized as it will block your UI thread which could cause an application not responding alert depending on how long the calculation takes.

Comment: I'm already using AsyncTask in my android app, but how do I wait in the mainFunction() for the work on the other thread to finish? Put a while loop that always checks if the work is done? This seems ugly to me. mainFunction() has to return the result of the calculations from the second thread.

Comment: You should never wait in your main thread. That will cause the application to be unresponsive. What you should do is in the onResult method of your async task update the view you need with the result. So if you're updating a text view. Save that textView as a variable then in onResult call setText on the textView with the result of the calculation.

Comment: But I will have several other functions that has to run in another thread. Then I will have to chain them: one onResult calls the other async task, and the onResult of this new async task calls another async task etc. etc. etc.. This is very very ugly. I just want a function that returns an int that is calculated on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of executing code in separate threads.
You can read about this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

I think that [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) will do what you want.

```
protected void onPreExecute () {
    // you can show some ProgressDialog indicating to the user that thread is working
}

protected Type doInBackground(String... args) {
    doWorkOnNewThread()
    // do your stuff here
}

protected void onPostExecute(Type result) {
    // here you can notify your activity that thread finished his job and dismiss ProgressDialog
}
```

Comment: I'm already using AsyncTask in my android app, but how do I wait in the mainFunction() for the work on the other thread to finish? Put a while loop that always checks if the work is done? This seems ugly to me. mainFunction() has to return the result of the calculations from the second thread.

Comment: You shouldnt wait in your UI Thread. I think your mainFunction() should run AsyncTask, and then AsyncTask should return result in its onPostExecute() method.

Comment: But then I will have to chain 5-6 onPostExecute() -s together since the next step uses the values from the previous step. This is very very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two way:
1. Asyntask
2. Handler

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static <T> T runSynchronouslyOnBackgroundThread(final Callable<T> callable) {
    T result = new Thread() {
      T callResult;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          callResult = callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }

      T startJoinForResult() {
        start();
        try {
          join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return callResult;
      }
    }.startJoinForResult();

    return result;
  }
```